# how to use cookies in javascript and html?

Tags: javascript, html

my question is I took one form like register form and fill al fields like first name, last name,address, check boxes  also used then when submit at final i want it to display those data in new page. Here I want code only in javascript and html. Is their possible please help me........... and send code and guide lines

Comment: You should not require people to use your email. THey might not want to reveal their own email and also, any answrs sent to your email will not be available to others looking for the same question.

Comment: that's not how we work here. Ask a specific question, get a specific answer.  Also, "give me teh code" questions aren't acceptable.  If you wish to hire a coder, there are plenty of sites where you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do that with cookies. Along those lines, I suggest using JQuery for your javascript development. JQuery makes cross-browser setting and retrieving cookies very easy.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Is not possible in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible through plain javascript also. Try it like this:

```
document.cookie = "name=value; expires=date; path=path; domain=domain; secure";
```

Example:

```
var cookie_date_str = new Date ( 2011, 01, 19 );
document.cookie = "username=chand;
                  expires=" + cookie_date_str.toGMTString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't use cookies any more, you can take advantage of the new HTML5 specifications and you can use the so called "localStorage" feature.
I recommend that you use jquery and it's magnificent plugins. A good example in this case is http://plugins.jquery.com/project/html5Storage , in wich case you could just do something like :

```
$('#formId')
  .children('input')
  .each(function(){
     $.Storage.set(
        $(this).attr('name'),
        $(this).val()
     );
  });
```

then,if you want to load the saved values , you will do something like :

```
$('#formId')
  .children('input')
  .each(function(){
     $(this).val($.Storage.get($(this).attr('name')));
  });
```

If tou want full browser compatibility , you should probably go with the cookie implementation,
but localStorage is supported by webkit based browsers, firefox, opera and IE 8 :), so it's only a matter of old browsers compatibility.